# Concatenate vector and a variable

Tags: matlab, variables, vector, concatenation

If I have a matrix

```
A = [0 1 0 1
     0 0 1 1]
```

and a variable `B = 121.23`, 
how can I concat both into a one variable.

I did

```
features_set = [A(:), B];
```

But, it gives an error CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

How can I add this variable B to the end of the vector A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A(:)` returns an 8-by-1 array. The comma appends along the second dimension. Thus, your code fails.

If the output should be a 9-by-1 array, you should write

```
features_set = [A(:);B];
```

If the output should be a 1-by-9 array, you should write

```
features_set = [A(:)',B];
```

Comment: Or features_set = [A(:)' B]; of course, depending on whether you want a Nx1 or 1xN vector.

Comment: yeah.. I need 9-by-1 array. So, your first solution is working.